# How do I customize comment characters in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code does not appear to understand that a less file should be treated as a css file when it comes to comment rules.  How can I tell it to treat a css and a less file the same?

Comment: Are you talking about highlighting? You should create an issue on the repo if there is an issue with highlighting https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: No, syntax highlighting is fine.  But when I select a line (or multiple lines) in a less file and type Ctrl + K, Ctrl+C, Code puts two slashes in front of each line instead of surrounding with /**/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode is behaving correctly in this case. Both `/* ... */` and `// ...` are valid comments in LESS, they do however differ slightly in the generated CSS:

- `/* ... */` will compile to `/* ... */`
- `// ...` will be removed during compilation

This allows comments to be removed, saving extra bytes from being transferred to the client. The double-slash style comment is typically what LESS developers use for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is an issue with vscode. There is currently no way to tell vscode how to treat **less** as **css**

You can use // or /**/ for commenting. Both of them works in vscode with syntax highlighting.