# How to change comment formatting in VS Code

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code

I am having the opposite problem than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853163/how-do-i-customize-comment-characters-in-vs-code): In a SASS .scss file, I want comments command (`ctrl/⌘ + /`, `ctrl/⌘ + K ctrl/⌘ + C`) to default to `//`, and use the Block comment `/* ... */` only when using the block comment (`shift+alt+A`).

I have been unable to find a way to change this setting, via the user settings or even a plugin. Is it possible? Is my google-fu just bad?

Answer (score 6):

A very belated answer, but you can amend the `language-configuration.json` file for the language in question. More here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide.

Comment: Where ist this file located?

Comment: Looks like this file (and these settings) are for if you create your own VSCode extension. I'm not seeing anywhere/way to do this in a settings file. Otherwise yes this is the way to fix this for any language  I'm voting for this answer as there's (literally) no other way to do this 

Comment: With a default installation these files are in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\<language>\language-configuration.json`. You need a restart for the changes to take effect

Answer (score 0):

It seems like at some point in the years since I posted this question, the default language behavior for sass / `.scss` files has changed and is behaving as I was wanting it to. (As observed in October 2023)